# Use middleware in outgoing request express js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have some express servers in a network. I communicate with each other with HTTP requests and using specific message types. Common request structure is like this,

```
{ 
  nonce: (randomNumber),
  type: messageType,
  message: {

  }
}
```

I encrypt the "message" (not the "nonce" or "type") with encryption algorithm A, B and C (depends on the message type). I learned that I can use express middleware to decrypt my incoming encrypted requests. How can I use middleware (or any other possible solution) to automatically encrypt outgoing requests based on the message type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no middleware for the outgoing request.

As a possible solution - you can wrap the request function and require it instead of request module.

For example:

*encrypted-request.js*:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch"); // used promise version of request lib
module.exports = (options) => {
  // encryption logic ...
  return fetch(options);
}
```

*some-controller.js*:

```
const fetch = require("./encrypted-fetch.js");


//just use as usual fetch somewhere
```

Comment: request-promise-native NPM package has been deprecated... https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native